# Why does pgsql claim the currval of sequence undefined even after calling nextval?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I'm working with a PostgresQL database, in which a trigger function logs changes to a history table.  I'm trying to add a column which keeps a logical "commit ID" to group master and detail records together.  I've created a (non-temporary) sequence, and before I start the batch of updates, I bump this.  All my SQL is logged to a log file, so you can clearly see this happening:

```
2015-04-16 10:43:37 SQLSelect: SELECT nextval('commit_id_seq')
2015-04-16 10:43:37 commit_id_seq: 8
```

...but then I attempt the UPDATE, my trigger function attempts to use currval, and it fails:

```
2015-04-16 10:43:37 ERROR: ERROR:  currval of sequence "commit_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO history (table_name, record_id, sec_user_id, created, action, notes, status, before, after, commit_id)
        SELECT TG_TABLE_NAME, rec.id, (SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = CURRENT_USER), now(), SUBSTR(TG_OP,1,1), note, stat, hstore(old), hstore(new), currval('commit_id_seq')"
PL/pgSQL function log_to_history() line 18 at SQL statement
 [3]
```

So my question is basically: WTF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of two reasons:

1. Search_path differences, so you're actually talking about two different sequences.
2. Different sessions. The "current value" is only defined for the session you call nextval() in.

You can add process-id to the logfile format to check if they are different sessions.

Comment: Well, the sequence isn't created in this session; I created it manually with an admin tool, and only once.  So, if it were a search path problem, I would expect a different error (along the lines of "no such sequence").

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by process-id, unless you mean the process ID of the app connecting to the DB.  But that's not it; it's a single-threaded app, and it's the only thing (other than the admin tool) connected to the DB, which is running locally and not accessible from the network.

Comment: Unless... maybe this app is making two separate connections to the DB.  That's possible.  Investigating now.

Comment: OK, that was it.  Same process, but two different connections, thus different sessions.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!